# Calculating and using maximum value of uint32_t

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I know that `UINT32_MAX` exists, but I haven't been able to use it. I tried `printf("%d\n", UINT32_MAX);` and it printed out `-1`. Using `%ld` instead of `%d` presented me with the error that `UINT32_MAX` is of the type unsigned int and needs `%d` to print it out.

Please help, what I ideally want is a macro/enum that holds the maximum value of `word_t` which is a type defined by me which currently is `uint32_t`.

I hope that I made clear what I want, if not please feel free to ask.

**EDIT**

I forgot to say what I'm actually trying to do. All of this will be used to set an array of integers all to their maximum value, because that array of integers actually is a bitmap that will set all bits to 1.

Comment: If you want to set an unsigned integer to all-bits-1, then just assign `-1` to it. The type doesn't matter (as long as it's unsigned), the representation of signed integers on the implementation doesn't matter, and you don't need to figure out the name of the macro for the correct max value (which makes it easier to deal with typedefs that might change in future).

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Is that just accidental behaviour or can you really rely on it?

Comment: it's guaranteed by the C standard. Signed-to-unsigned conversion is 6.3.1.3/2, and representation of unsigned int types is 6.2.6.2/1 (although actually you don't care about the storage representation, you just care that `-1` is converted to unsigned by "adding one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type", and hence `-1` converted to any unsigned type is UTYPE_MAX).

Comment: I know it might be useless to talk about a "correct" way... but shouldn't ~0 be better than -1... I mean, ~0 is what you actually want, -1 just gives ~0 as a side-effect of addition/subtraction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The portable way to print a `uintN_t` object is to cast it to a `uintmax_t` and use the `j` length modifier with the `u` conversion specifier:

```
printf("%ju\n", (uintmax_t)(UINT32_MAX));
```

The `j` means that the argument is either an `intmax_t` or a `uintmax_t`; the `u` means it is unsigned, so it is a `uintmax_t`.

Or, you can use the format strings defined in `<inttypes.h>` (n this case, you'd use `PRIu32`):

```
printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", UINT32_MAX);
```

You can't just use `%u` because it isn't guaranteed that `int` is represented by at least 32 bits (it only needs to be represented by at least 16 bits).

Comment: There's `PRIu32` in `inttypes.h`, for the common case where the format string is defined in the same source code as the `printf` statement. If the format string is defined somewhere else that might not be compatible, then it's no good.

Comment: Thanks a lot, doesn't really matter though, the use of this won't be the printing out, but this answer made me understood what the issue was. Accepted.

Comment: @Steve:  Interesting; I didn't know those were in there!

Comment: I mention them as someone who can never be bothered to actually use the things. Other than debugging (in which case you know the implementation), `printf` is UI programming. I don't do UIs in C ;-)

Comment: `long` is at least 32-bits so `%lu` and `(unsigned long)UINT32_MAX` paired together should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You encountered your specific problem because `%d` is a signed formatter.

There are a number of ways to fix it (two have already been suggested), but the *really* correct way is to use the format specifiers defined in `<inttypes.h>`:

```
uint32_t number;
printf("number is %" PRIu32 "\n", number);
```

Answer (score 2):

`%d` is for signed integers. Use `%u`.

EDIT: Ignore this answer and use James's, which is more complete.

Comment: What if `int` is represented by 16 bits?

Comment: @James Well, I would use your answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting an array of unsigned int to the max values you could do it via memset:

memset(array, 0xFF, sizeof(unsigned int) * arraysize);

Comment: This won't work at all, 0xFF is completely unrelated to `uint32_t`.

Comment: It fills the block of memory one byte at a time with 0xFF. 4 bytes per int * arraysize.

Comment: Provided that `CHAR_BIT == 8`, this is correct for `uint32_t` (as in the question), because `uint32_t` is guaranteed not to have padding bits. It's technically not portable for `unsigned int`, since that *is* permitted to have padding bits and if so this might create a trap representation. But we also know from the question that on the implementation the questioner is using, the two types are the same anyway. So +1 to counter an unjustified -1. `0xFF` *is* related to `uint32_t`, assuming 8 bit bytes. With 16 bit bytes this would be wrong, so better to use `-1` than `0xff`.

Comment: @Steve: The only way `uint32_t` can exist is if `CHAR_BIT` is 8, 16, or 32. The assumption would go away if you just replace `0xFF` with `-1`. :-)